# Wireless connection to internet drops off when other PC is turned off

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

I have a PC and a laptop connected to a wireless router leading to the internet.

When both the PC (wired) and laptop (wireless) are turned on, the internet connection from both is fine.

However, if I turn of the PC, the laptop can no longer connect to the internet.

Can anyone explain what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess -- that PC was initially configured to connect to the modem directly. Later, you added the router and never reconfigured that PC to a normal configuration.

If your Internet connection requires PPPoE or PPPoA or some other special configuration, you need to make that configuration in the *router*. And you need to remove any special network configuration from any PCs that shouldn't have it.

Otherwise, your PC is actually terminating your Internet connection and your router is just acting as a switch.

Comment: yeah, but it worked perfectly before! it started acting like this last 2 days. But I will check you advice thank you David